# How many ways to get an odd number of each color in each bin?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have an odd number of white balls and the same number of blacks balls.

> How many different ways are there of putting the balls into bins so
>   that you have an odd number of each color in each bin?

For example, if you have $3$ white and $3$ black there are $2$ different ways. You either put them all in one bin or one white and one black in each of $3$ bins.  For $5$ white and $5$ white balls there are $4$ different ways.  These are:

```
(wwwwwbbbbb)
(wwwbbb)(wb)(wb)
(wwwb)(wbbb)(wb)
(wb)(wb)(wb)(wb)(wb)
```

Comment: Generating function: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty(x+x^3+x^5+x^7+\dots)^k(y+y^3+y^5+\dots)^k$ and looking at the coefficient of $x^ay^b$ where $a$ is the number of white balls and $b$ is the number of black balls.

Comment: @JMoravitz Does this give you 12 for $a = b = 7$?

Comment: No, it gives much more than that.  My initial comment assumes that the bins are each labeled.  For 5 balls each I come to a total of 11 outcomes (one outcome each for one bin or five bins, and then with 3 bins it is broken into cases of which bin gets the three balls of each color for 9 more cases)  If you intend the bins to be unlabeled, then my approach doesn't work.

Comment: For 7 black and 7 white, if my mental calculations are correct I get 63 outcomes.

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah no it really should be 4 for 5 white balls. I will add them explicitly to the question.

Comment: For $n = 1,3,5,\dots$ we get number of solutions $1, 2, 4, 12, 32, 85, 217, 539, 1316, 3146, 7374, 16969, 38387, 85452, 187456$. Sequence can not be found in OEIS from what I can see. [Code to calculate this found here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162253/count-the-number-of-ways-of-putting-balls-into-bins/162275#162275).

Comment: Dropping the odd requirement gives [OEIS A108469](https://oeis.org/A108469).

Comment: @orlp I've added this to the OEIS as sequence A302919. (It won't appear in the Encylopedia until the draft is approved.)

Comment: @PeterKagey I think "The number of ways of placing 2n-1 white balls and 2n-1 black balls into an equal number of unlabeled bins such that each bin has both an odd number of white balls and black balls." should be "The number of ways of placing 2n-1 white balls and 2n-1 black balls into unlabeled bins such that each bin has both an odd number of white balls and black balls.

Comment: @Anush, I've submitted an edit. The initial draft was approved, so here's the permanent link for reference: https://oeis.org/A302919.

Comment: Since there is no reason to restrict oneself to an odd number of white and black balls for this problem, it would have been better for OEIS to have the series that allows any number. Now OEIS got a series that is a subseries of a more natural one...

Comment: My comment above about dropping the odd requirement assumed balls of each color in each bin. If we allow bins with only balls of one color, we get [OEIS A002774](https://oeis.org/A002774).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cycle  index $Z(S_n)$  of the  symmetric group  (multiset operator
$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}     \def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm     #1{\small
#2}}}\textsc{MSET}$) has $Z(S_0)=1$ and the recurrence

$$Z(S_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{l=1}^n a_l Z(S_{n-l}).$$

Extracting coefficients from this Maple will produce

$$1, 2, 4, 12, 32, 85, 217, 539, 1316, 3146, 7374, 16969, 38387, 85452, 
\\ 187456, 405659, 866759, 1830086, 3821072, 7894447, 16148593, 
\\ 32723147, 65719405, 130871128, 258513076, 506724988,
\ldots$$ 
where we have used memoization.

The repertoire here was 
$$f(W, B) = \sum_{p_1=0}^q \sum_{p_2=0}^q W^{2p_1+1} B^{2p_2+1},$$

the substitution $a_l = f(W^l, B^l)$  and the coefficient being extracted

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2q+1} [W^{2q+1}] [B^{2q+1}] Z(S_k)(f(W,B)).$$

The Maple code runs as follows.

```
X :=
proc(n, q, q1, q2)
option remember;

    if n = 0 then
        if q1 = 0 and q2 = 0 then
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
        fi;
    fi;

    add(add(add(X(n-l, q, q1-(2*p1+1)*l, q2-(2*p2+1)*l),
                p2=0..floor((q2/l-1)/2)),
            p1=0..floor((q1/l-1)/2)),
        l=1..n)/n;
end;

R := q -> add(X(k, q, 2*q+1, 2*q+1), k=1..2*q+1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! What do you think the asymptotics might be?

Answer (score 3):

More general, the coefficient of $x^my^n$ in

$$ \prod_{i,j\geq 0}(1-x^{2i+1}y^{2j+1})^{-1} $$

tells you how many ways there are to distribute $m$ white and $n$ black balls into bins such that each bin contains an odd number of white and an odd number of black balls.

There is a correspondance between the partitions of a number into *odd* numbers and those of the same number into *different* numbers. The same idea gives a correspondance between the ways to put balls into bins according to the given rules and the ways to put the balls into bins such that no two bins have the same contents and, for each bin, the number of white balls and the number of black balls is divisible by the same power of two (they have the same $2$-adic valuation). For example, a bin with $6$ and $10$ balls is allowed, but a bin with $6$ and $12$ balls isn't.

Hence the generating function can also be expressed as

$$ \prod (1+x^iy^j) $$

where the product is over all pairs of positive integers $i$ and $j$ such that $i$ and $j$ have the same $2$-adic valuation (i.e. there is an integer $k$ such that $(i,j)=2^k\cdot (r,s)$ for some odd integers $r$ and $s$).

Comment: Can you explain the $-1$ exponent?

Comment: @qwr Recall the geometric series $(1-z)^{-1}=1+z+z^2+\dots$ and let $z=x^ry^s$ for some odd $r$ and $s$. The corresponding factor will allow for any number of bins having $r$ white and $s$ black balls.

Comment: What do you think the asymptotics might be if $m = n$? It seems it might be asymptotic to $\sqrt{2}^n$ but it's hard to tell.

Comment: @Anush Extracting information about asymptotics from generating functions seems to be much more difficult in the multivariate case. From other series involving partitions I expect something more complicated.

Comment: @Anush $f(501)/f(499)\approx 1.39$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will ask about the asymptotics separately.